# Windows Forms Application Console Output

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I have an application that can be ran both from UI and `cmd`. When it runs from console I need to print something as output. Here's `Main()` method:

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        foreach (var arg in args)
        {
            if (arg == "-T")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Example!!!"); //Nothing happens
                return;
            }
        }

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

How to print output in such cases?

Comment: what happened exactly? did console window disappear after a flash instead of showing output??

Comment: No it did not disappear. I've ran my app using `app.exe -T` in `cmd` window.

Comment: Well it seems nothing wrong with the code, add [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) in your code to read line from input stream.

Comment: It just stops on line Console.ReadLine

Comment: Can you please update your code here?

Comment: I do have a vague memory of this working before, it's been too long.  You really *do* need to change Project > Properties > Application > Output Type to Console Application.  Not what you want to do since that always creates a console window, the workaround is to make a puny console mode project that launches your winapp exe when needed.